# elegant way to convert IP to octal

Tags: php

I have been looking for an elegant way in php to convert an IP address into its octal representation without having to do each of the four digits separately.

for example, the IP: 1.2.3.4 would be 0001.0002.0003.0004

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. It would be better if you can edit it and explain exactly what you want. Maybe give an example of input and desired output

Comment: i thought it was pretty clear. for example, the IP: 1.2.3.4 would be 0001.0002.0003.0004

Comment: I suppose 127.0.0.1 would become 0177.0000.0000.0001?  That's dotted-octal, not just octal (which would be the 32-bit IP address interpreted as a single numeric value).  I have never encountered an application for IP addresses in dotted-octal form, but in any case,I believe you have to split, convert, and rejoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str_ip = '255.2.3.4';
echo vsprintf("%04o.%04o.%04o.%04o", sscanf($str_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d"));
//0377.0002.0003.0004
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid looping, though you can use array_walk to avoid typing for.  You might also want to cast $value as a string and pad it out with zeros.

```
$ip = '123.12.23.34';
$ip_a = explode('.', $ip);
array_walk($ip_a, function(&$value, $key){ $value = decoct($value); });
echo implode('.',$ip_a);
```